# Preventing traffic going to a new ECS task while it still builds a NextJS static site

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, next.js, amazon-ecs

I have an AWS ECS task that runs a single container. Inside that container runs nginx, as well as a Next.js application.

My problem is that when I deploy, the ECS task spins up and is registered in the load balancer target group before Next.js has finished its "npm run build" command. This results in about 5 minutes of users getting a 502 error on the site, as traffic is going through to nginx and then to Next, which hasn't started yet and is still building.

Is there a way to manually tell ECS that this task should not be in "RUNNING" state until after the build process has completed?

Comment: do you have load balancer?

Comment: I think you have fundamentally get it wrong (no offense). Your build (npm run build) should be part of the container building process (in a dockerfile) Your Next.js up should spin up in seconds, not 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @SándorBakos - no offense taken. Unfortunately our pipeline is outside of AWS and that pipeline doesn't have any connectivity to the CMS application from which it pulls content, as that CMS is within a restricted network. Thus, running npm run build in the current pipeline is not possible. But your comment is helpful nonetheless, as I may need to explore another pipeline solution. Thank you.